# How do I move a folder back to parent mailbox in Apple mail

Tags: apple-mail

So I accidentally dropped a mail folder into the wrong folder. For some strange reason I'm not able to move it back to the parent folder. I just upgrade to Mavericks so I'm wondering if something in Apple mail has changed. I don't remember this being impossible. How do I move the folder back to the parent mailbox. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the account. Logged into OWA, moved the folder there. Re-added the account. Then I threw the machine out windows.